# How do I remove the default program associated with an .exe in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

Something really strange happened about 10 minutes ago. I tried to open a file named `pdfsam.exe` and instead of running it, Windows 7 asked me to choose a program to open the file with.

Without realizing what I was getting into, I accidentally selected `Windows Media Center` (if I remember correctly it was selected by default) and then I clicked <kbd>OK</kbd>.

To my horror, whichever program I try to run now starts the `Windows Media Center`. Here are a few things I have already tried:

1. Tried running `regedit.exe` using the <kbd>Win + R</kbd> combo: opens the `Windows Media Center`
2. Tried accessing `Turn Windows features on or off`: opens the `Windows Media Center`
3. Tried running `cmd`, both a. from the Start button search box and b. <kbd>Win + R</kbd>: this too opens the `Windows Media Center`!

I am completely at a loss here. Apparently I am the only idiot on the internet to have done this (or I am not able to ask Google the right question). I am worried that after I shutdown this browser I won't be able to open it again. The next thing I am going to try is to perform a system restore to a past date. If that fails all I will be left to is to perform searches using my smartphone.

Comment: If you haven't disabled [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore), this might be a time to use it.  If your last restore point wasn't that long ago anyway?

Comment: I don't suppose you have Remote Registry enabled? :P

Comment: Possible solution: http://www.askvg.com/solution-exe-files-always-open-with-notepad-or-other-applications/ `If you can't open "regedit", press CTRL+ALT+DEL keys and open "Task Manager". Now click on "File" menu and hold down the "CTRL" key and click on "New Task" menu. It'll open a Command Prompt window. Now provide regedit.exe command and press Enter. It'll open registry editor without any problem.`. After this you could manually change the entries. Otherwise... Microsoft (link on that page) offers a .MSI to fix this problem.

Comment: Direct link to the Microsoft solution with the .MSI file (which can correct this problem): http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2688326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what solved it for me. The complete solution is available at [support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950505) which probably makes the link unlikely to go dead anytime soon.

The primary objective is to get to the `cmd` prompt.

1. Start task manager with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
2. From `File` select `New Task (Run…)` **while holding down the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button.**
3. Start command prompt by entering `cmd` and then execute the necessary commands from the `cmd` prompt to solve the problem.

I guess half the battle is won by getting to the command prompt. The rest of the solution provided on the link works of course, but most experienced users of the Windows OS can perhaps manage without it as well.

Comment: Ack: thanks to @Rik for the comments to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You are *not* alone in having that issue. There is a site, [Default File Associations - Restore](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) that can generate a .REG file to resolve the issue. *This has not been tested by me*, so use caution, examine the .REG file and back up the Registry before applying it.

Please let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: An excellent resource. I am worried about the potential for this to become a dead answer as it hinges entirely on that one link, but I can't think of any other way of supplying a .REG file.

Comment: @MichaelFrank a reg file could be pasted in and scroll bars would be added. though the link there seems to be a zip with a load of reg files

Comment: @barlop The reg file is 84 lines. Seems overly spammy to paste in it's entirety. There are also individual .REG files for each extensions.

Comment: @MichaelFrank not really spammy. Bear in mind that on stackoverflow for android java programming,. people paste in quite a lot of code 'cos java is quite verbose and xml is verbose and even a simple program requires a number of files..  The contents of any of the individual reg files is really not long.

Comment: This answer could be improved by simply supplying the registry file to solve the .exe extension default file association.  I don't find this answer particularly helpful of course because the entire problem is that the author cannot even run `regedit` or so its doubtful this solution can even be used.